# What is the right way to verify if local Storage variable exists? - XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I'm doing an app that has a login, and it has the option to keep you login even if you turn off the app.

What is the problem? This is what I'm doing this in App.cs:

```
  var statusLog = Application.Current.Properties["logStatus"].ToString();
        if (statusLog == "F")
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

        }
        else
        {
            var userStore = (Application.Current.Properties["user"].ToString());
            Task.Run(() =>  lp.GetTokenLogin()).Wait();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ConfirmarViatura(userStore));




        }
```

It works fine, but their is one situation that it do not work, that is if I run the app for the first time in the device, it gives me a exception that the local variable "logStatus" do not exists. 
I understand it do not exists, but how can i do this verification?
**I can't do this** :

```
          if (Application.Current.Properties["logStatus"].Equals(null))
        {
            Application.Current.Properties["logStatus"] = "F";

        }
```

This do not work because the variable dosen't even exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check it this way:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("logStatus"))
{
    var statusLog = Application.Current.Properties["logStatus"] as string;
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check first if it exists, then do your logic and assigning.

```
if (App.Current.Properties.Exists("logStatus"))
```

Comment: IDictionary<string,object> does not contain a definition for "Exists" and no acessible extension method "Exists" accepting a first argument of type "Idictionary<string,object> could be found.